# Access localhost from Android device

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

I have a server in xampp in os x laptop, when I type: 10.0.2.2/myphpServer in the emulator web navigator, goes ok, but from a usb-connected real android device, I can not connect.

Comment: Pls check if Internet permission set in Manifest file or not? If already, try using the real IP of your PC. 10.0.2.2 is used for emulator.

Comment: Yes, manifest has Internet permission

Comment: Use real IP instead. Try access realIP/... from web browser in your phone. Check Network connection, firewall. And more, post your logcat :-)

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: solved. Used 10.0.2.2 for emulator and real IP for real android device

Comment: Good news, however, I  think you should accept one of the below working answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check public ip of your pc   by `ifconfig` command in terminal
then use `YOUR_IP/myphpServer`
If you are in local network (router or LAN) then use your `local_ip/myphpServer` (make sure your mobile is also in same network)

If your mobile doesn't have internet connection then go for [Android USB Tethering](http://www.mactip.net/usb-tethering-a-mac-to-an-android-phone/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect both device to same network to access localhost in Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the IP Address of your laptop type in cmd `ipconfig` search for **Local Area Connection: IPv4 Address**